# Anyone have good examples of Terraform getting a remote json and assigning TF variables as a module to be consumed by multipe .tf projects?

Tags: json, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So I'm looking for some good examples of a module where I can remotely grab a json file and assign TF variables inside of a module to be consumed by several different terraform projects.

I'm new to TF and I know you can get he file like this:

```
module "get-my-json": {
   source="https://www.example.com/files/test.json"
}
```

but need some help in figuring out how to assign these to variables and for that module to be consumed by other tf projects.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to specify a remotely stored TF var JSON file for the root module?

Comment: Sort of. I want to basically call the json file then assign it variables inside my main.tf to be able to use. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a [terraform_remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/language/state/remote-state-data). Another option is to store configuration information into SSM parameter store.